# Asterisk res_config_mysql module is missing

Tags: mysql, asterisk

I have installed asterisk latest package and using mysql DB for realtime simulation. But in the CLI i am getting the error:

```
config.c:2444 find_engine: Realtime mapping for 'sippeers' found to engine 'mysql', but the engine is not available
```

and while executing command  `MODULE LOAD RES_CONFIG_MYSQL` i am getting the following message.

```
loader.c:918 load_resource: Module 'RES_CONFIG_MYSQL' could not be loaded.
```

My machine is with linux mint 16. 64 bit.

Comment: How you installed asterisk? have you ever configured /etc/asterisk/res_config_mysql.conf?

Comment: i have installed asterisk by downloading the tar.gz package. I have configured res_config_mysql.conf as follows:
`[general]
dbhost = localhost
dbname = a2billing
dbuser = root
dbpass = 19941992
dbport = 3306`

Comment: and i have checked. there is no `RES_CONFIG_MYSQL.so` file in the location /usr/lib/asterisk/module

Answer (score 0):

If you have version <1.4 you have download asterisk-addons and compile it too

Otherwise you have do 
 `make menuconfig`

before make and select mysql addon