# res_mysql_config.so module is missing. Can not install it

Tags: mysql, linux, asterisk

I have installed asterisk latest package and using mysql DB for realtime simulation.I can not find any re_mysql_config.so file in the module folder.And in the CLI i am getting the error:

```
config.c:2444 find_engine: Realtime mapping for 'sippeers' found to engine 'mysql', but the engine is not available
```

and while executing command  `MODULE LOAD RES_CONFIG_MYSQL` i am getting the following message.

```
loader.c:918 load_resource: Module 'RES_CONFIG_MYSQL' could not be loaded. How can i install the module? I have tried. But failed several times.
```

Asterisk version: Asterisk 11.8.1

My machine is with linux mint 16. 64 bit.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: But i found asterisk and mysql category here. :)

Comment: yes, but you're not asking a programming question. you're asking about systems configuration. that's like saying you can ask how to make spaghetti, because programmers need to eat at some point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asterisk res\_config\_mysql module is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502236/asterisk-res-config-mysql-module-is-missing)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the installation type, the res_mysql_config.so module will be available via different methods. For example, if you've installed from distribution packages, most probably there is a packages called asterisk-addons-mysql or something like that.

If you've compiled Asterisk from source distribution, you will be required to make sure to mark these as enabled, via 'make menuconfig'. If you will be missing the mysql development dependency, it will alert you via the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Have you install asterisk-modules and asterisk-mysql addons?
Have you loaded the proper .so's in /etc/asterisk/modules ?